# Remove duplicates from my listbox and add it again with the number of duplication

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm building a Point of Sale system. I used a `FlowLayoutPanel` that creates buttons for my products. So once I click on that button it transfers the product to a `listbox`. Now I'm stuck with how will I enter the quantity of that product?

I tried to make a form with numbers (like a calculator) that when I press the button it pops up but I couldn't. So now I have this idea that if I click a certain product's button twice for example,  Instead of putting it twice in the `listbox` it puts it once and put 2 in the quantity column.

So I think I need some kind of a loop that loops every time I click that button. Is that possible?

Please help me, any ideas or comments are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is all the codes regarding the 'ListBox' :

```
public RegisterForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        ChosenProductsList.DataSource = products;
        ChosenProductsList.DisplayMember = "Name";

        CreateTappedPanel();
        AddProdToTapPanel();
    }

void UpdateProductList (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Button b = (Button)sender;                           
        ProductTBL p = (ProductTBL)b.Tag;                   

        products.Add(p);
        ChosenProductsList.SelectedIndex = ChosenProductsList.Items.Count - 1;                   
    }

private void FormatListItem(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        string CurrentName = ((ProductTBL)e.ListItem).Name;
        string currentPrice = String.Format("{0:c}", ((ProductTBL)e.ListItem).Price);
        string currentNamePadded = CurrentName.PadRight(20);

        e.Value = currentNamePadded + currentPrice;
    }
```

Comment: It should be easy enough. You can iterate over the `Items` member of the `ListBox` and manipulate the one you're after, provided you don't continue looking after you've removed an item. Alternatively, you might prefer a `StackPanel` with a custom control to do something like a web shopping cart (or the **Related** column over to the right on this page), if you have the real estate.

Comment: @JohnC This is Winforms, not WPF.

Comment: Sorry i didn't specify it is winforms.

Comment: Please take a look at how SO questions are expected to look and improve it by making more readable. We make our code look well-organized and beautiful, why not to follow this good tradition when we ask questions? ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Using LINQ you can achieve that easily with [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Count()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods :**

Example :

```
internal class VideoGame
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var game1 = new VideoGame {Name = "MegaMan"};
var game2 = new VideoGame {Name = "Super Mario Bros"};
var game3 = new VideoGame {Name = "Kirby"};

var list = new List<VideoGame>();
list.Add(game1);
list.Add(game2);
list.Add(game2);
list.Add(game3);
list.Add(game3);
list.Add(game3);

IEnumerable<VideoGame> videoGames = list.Distinct();
var enumerable = videoGames.Select(s => new {VideoGame = s, Count = list.Count(t => t.Name == s.Name)});
```

Now I transform `enumerable` to a string so you can see the result :

```
var @join = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, enumerable.Select(s => string.Format("VideoGame: {0}, Count: {1}", s.VideoGame.Name, s.Count)));
```

Output :

```
VideoGame: MegaMan, Count: 1
VideoGame: Super Mario Bros, Count: 2
VideoGame: Kirby, Count: 3
```

Note that I've used an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) but you can use your own type instead.

I leave you the task of updating your ListBox, should be fairly easy to do :D

Comment: i tried your answer but it gives errors could you please check the code i included and tell me how to use your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the listbox, one of its main advantages, is that it will accept any object as an item.  This means that you can create your own object, override the ToString method to display the data you want, and if you want the selected item returned you simply cast it back to the original type.

```
public class Item
{
    public string name = "";
    public int count = 0;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Create a list of `Item`

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item{name = "A", count = 1},
    new Item{name = "B", count = 1},
};
```

Populate the listbox.  The `ToString` method is used

```
listbox1.DataSource = items;
```

To increment the count find the item in the Items collection, cast it to `Item` and increment the count property
To use the selected item

```
Item pickeditem = (Item)listbox1.SelectedItem;
```